# How to deploy Spring Boot application to Google Managed VM

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, spring-boot, google-compute-engine

I have a Spring Boot application and I'm trying to figure out the bits to deploy it to Google's new Managed VM environment (these are VMs capable of running Docker containers). I've started down the road of defining an app.yaml with the following:

```
application: myapp-1
version: 1
runtime: java
api_version: 1
vm: true
handlers:
  - url: /*
  servlet: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  init_params:
    contextAttribute: org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT
```

I then run the following to test things out from my application root:

```
gcloud --verbosity debug preview app run .
```

I've been doing some trial and error and now getting the following exception:

```
Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap 
    secure=default 
    static_files=None 
    application_readable=None 
    auth_fail_action=redirect 
    require_matching_file=None 
    static_dir=None 
    redirect_http_response_code=None 
    http_headers=None 
    url=/* 
    script=None 
    upload=None 
    api_endpoint=None 
    expiration=None 
    position=None 
    login=optional 
    mime_type=None
    >
```

I'm using https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml as a guide but I'm starting to doubt the Managed VM environment supports the app.yaml format.

There's a similar example here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-guestbook-extras but it doesn't use the app.yaml format.

Are there any recent examples for getting a Spring Boot app to run in a Google Managed VM?

Answer (score 1):

I only saw an example of running a SprinBoot app on Google AppEngine https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-sample-gae

Google has also added [few hints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization) on how to optimize a SpringApp for Google AppEngine (which I think it applies to Google Managed Vm as well)

You can also check on SpringBoot deployment hints (http://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications) especially the part with deploying into Jetty Containers (usually GAE is using Jetty container afaik)

I'm also trying to deploy such a SpringBoot app that uses the GoogleDatastore on ManagedVm, so I will soon let you know about my findings! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

YAML files used indentation to precisely define structure. Can you try to indent the lines for `servlet` and `init_params` by however many spaces are needed until they line up as the examples do [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml)? Or is this just a case of StackOverflow breaking your YAML as pasted?